# define('HOME', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' ); only works on development site

Tags: php

I changed my directory structure around so I needed to adjust all my includes links to be relative. The only way I could do this was to place

```
define('HOME', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );
```

in my index.php file and adjust the relative links from there. However, this only works on my development site. If I move the whole thing onto a live site, say, as a subdirectory, it gets messed up. For example, on my dev site, the url of the project is

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\darkerslate\index.php.
```

On my live site, I have it as a subdirectory:

```
http://mywebsite.com/darkerslate/index.php.
```

The problem is, with HOME defined like this, any links to index.php now point to:

```
http://mywebsite.com/home/myname/public_html/darkerslate/index.php.
```

How can I define the home of the project as being index.php so it will work if I want to put the project in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

`__DIR__` relates to the filename, but has absolutely nothing to do with the url you use to access the script in a browser. The fact that it works on your development site is completely coincidental.

If you are looking for the current URI that is being used to access the script, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: No, I basically need the relative links to work regardless of if the project is in the root directory or a subdirectory. For example, if I put a link in my navbar that goes to "/index.php" it will work on my development server, but on my live site it will take me to "mysite.com/index.php" instead of "mysite.com/project/index.php".

Comment: I understand, and you can get to the 'directory' by using the REQUEST_URI.